# Selecting all fields with values greater than a current field value

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I have a table that looks like this.

| path_id | step | point_id | delay_time | stand_time | access |

|     202 |    1 |      111 |          0 |          0 |      7 |

Which lists point_id's in step order.
E.g.: 111 - step 1, 181 - step 2, etc.

I need to write a query that would take point_id, select ALL values which have higher step within ALL path_id's that have a given value and return a grouped set of point_id's.

I am currently using this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT `pdb`.`point_id` AS `id` 
FROM `path_detail` AS `pda` INNER JOIN 
`path_detail` AS `pdb` ON pda.path_id = pdb.path_id 
 AND pda.step < pdb.step
WHERE 
(pda.point_id = 111) 
GROUP BY `pdb`.`path_id`
```

Which doesn't seem to work too reliably.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "I need to write a query that would take point_id, select ALL values which have higher step within ALL path_id's that have a given value and return a grouped set of point_id's." Err... what? Can you demonstrate with a worked example?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work reliably?  Can you show schema for both tables in question?  Can you show sample output you would like to see?

Comment: Aite, I'll try to elaborate. Let's say I pass a point_id that has a step value of 10, within path_id 202. Thus I need steps 11 and onwards selected from rows with  path_id of 202. Then, I'll need to check the rows with path_id of 203, 204 and so on, returning a distinct set of values. In a more real-world example, I'm passing a city id, expecting to find all cities that the transport will arrive to after it. As far as the query I provided goes - I'm quite certain it only return one value per path_id, while there can be multiple ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT Distinct `pdb`.`point_id` AS `id` 
FROM `path_detail` AS `pda`, `path_detail` AS `pdb`  
WHERE 
pda.point_id = 111
AND pda.path_id = pdb.path_id 
AND pda.step < pdb.step
Order by `pdb`.`point_id` ASC
```

Comment: DISTINCT really should be there, otherwise I get more than 5000 rows fetched. Seems to work otherwise, thanks.